# Can't connect Firebase Auth to Angular Web App, Page solely reloads

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've been trying to implement Firebase Auth for a while now. I followed a lot of tutorial, but [this one](https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-course-firebase-authentication/) represents my current version of code.

I imported `AngularFireModule` and `AngularFireAuthModule` to `app.module.ts`. Additionally I created the following service and created a login which calls the methods from the service.

I know the service is being called successfully since console.log returns the correct input. Additionally the page reloads, but nothing happens ('?' is added to the link when it reloads).

Does anyone know the issue? I'm already using Firebase Hosting, hence I assume I've implemented Firebase correctly.

```
export class AuthService {
  user: User;


  constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, public router: Router) {
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.user = user;
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.user));
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem('user', null);
      }
    });
  }

  async login(email: string, password: string) {
    try {
      console.log('uff');
      await  this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
      this.router.navigate(['admin']);
    } catch (e) {
      alert('Error!'  +  e.message);
    }
  }

  get isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    const  user  =  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    return  user  !==  null;
  }

  async logout() {
    await this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
    localStorage.removeItem('user');
    this.router.navigate(['']);
  }

}
```

Routing:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: FrontComponent },
  { path: 'cases', component: CaseListComponent },
  { path: 'cases/:id', component: TemplateComponent },
  { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent },
  { path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent, children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'front', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
      { path: 'front', component: FrontComponent },
    ]},
];
```

Login:

```
<div class="container-fluid min-vh-100 d-flex justify-content-center">

  <form class="align-self-center">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email address</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" #email required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" #password required>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="authService.login(email.value, password.value)">Submit</button>
  </form>

</div>

<li *ngIf="authService.isLoggedIn" class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link"  (click)="authService.logout()">Logout</a>
</li>



Typescript:
constructor(public authService: AuthService) { }
```